# Adding JcomboBox in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have created a form in which I have added a `jTable`
which has 3 columns. 2nd and 3rd  column have `jcombobox` editor.

I want that when we select the first item of the 2nd column combobox
first combobox of the 3rd column combobox should also be selected and vice-versa.

How can I do that?

Comment: any code to show how far you are or what you are struggling with? for help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You can add `ActionListener` to each `ComboBox` that will select first item from another column

Answer (score 2):

You can try to override `public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)` method and check when value is set to the edited column you should also call `setValueAt()` for the first column.